# Telerik grid shows an empty column after delete command

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am using Telerik MVC Extensions Grid control, with AJAX binding, and run a delete command.  Deletion works as intended, and the grid updates so that it doesn't show the deleted row.

However, after deleting one of the grid columns (the first one) shows up empty. There is also difference in the second column - 'false' instead of the unchecked box. 
Any ideas why, and how do I fix that?

I can refresh the screen, and that fixes the view. But it is a heavy page, and I'd rather not do the second refresh.

[image: Delete first row:]

After deleting, the first column shows up empty:
[image: Now first column is empty:]

My grid:

```
Html.Telerik()
    .Grid(Model)
    .Name("scenarioGrid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                    .Delete("Delete", "Scenario"))
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(o => Html.ActionLink(o.Name, "Index", new {id = o.Name})).Title("Scenario")
                .FooterTemplate(@<text>Total @Model.Count() </text>);
            columns.Bound(o => o.IsLocked);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ContractMonth);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CreateDate);
            columns.Command(commands => commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)).Title("Delete");
        }
    )
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scroll => scroll.Height(200))
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDelete("onDelete").OnComplete("afterDelete"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `columns.Template` with Ajax binding.  It's meant for server side bound grids.  You should use

```
columns.Bound(o => 0.whatever).ClientTemplate("convert your link to a string here");
```

Comment: Can you help with syntax for client template?

Comment: @jprusakova I'm sure someone here can.  Just add a question with what you're having trouble with.  Chances are, it will get resolved for you:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using server binding to load the grid, but ajax binding to update it. columns.Template is used for server binding. You should use ClientTemplate for ajax binding.